# Why would MS Access Split form show different values in Form and Datasheet views?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a split form, one of the fields is price. In Form view part of that form, I get 4,000.00 €, but in Datasheet part I get 4,00 €. The correct value is 4,00 €. I didn't do any formatting of that field in my form, so under Property list -> Formatting it's empty. If I choose Currency there, then the values reverse, so in the Form view part I get 4,00 €, and in Datasheet part I get 4,000.00 €.

Another thing I noticed is thet if I go to DataSource of that particular field, and then change formatting of the value to Currency there, I do get the right value on both ends, but that doesn't seem to save no matter what, so when I close and reopen the form, I have the same issue as before

What could be causing that?

Comment: If anyone ever has the same problem, I kind of solved it with creating extra Query, where I only listed IDs and Prices, and than extracted the Price value from that Query instead of direct from the table. It works now.

Comment: You must be mixing something in an unconventional way unknown to us. This is not a general issue. So, double-check your doings.

Comment: What is data type of Price field - Currency? I cannot replicate issue but then I am not using Euro currency.

Comment: check if the data type is a numeric field. Also, check if there is any specified format for the field in the table definition. Check also that your number format configuration at OS level match with that you are expecting: Access default behaviour for numeric formats will depend on the OS configuration